# only the coloured part of my UIView to handle events

Tags: objective-c, uiview, event-handling

I have a UIImageView, and it shows a picture of a woman, and everything other than the woman is completely transparent. I would like to only make the non-transparent part to handle events, while the transparent part should pass the event up the responder chain.  do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...
You have that image view frame. So you can handle events with touches. If you touch with in the imageview frame you can handle event otherwise you don't do anything.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    startX = touchLocation.x;
    startY = touchLocation.y;
  }
```

You can compare that startX and startY with imageview frames.